# jquery - show/hide unique content with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, hide, show

I'm trying to show and hide content with checkboxes.
I have 7 types of fruit salad. 
They are as so:
1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Pear
4. Apple-Orange
5. Orange-Pear
6. Apple-Pear
7. Apple-Orange-Pear
I want the customer to be able to select their fruit using the 3 check boxes to select the type of salad they want. If the customer chooses, apple I only want apple to show, if they choose orange, i only want orange to show. If they choose apple-orange, i only want the apple-orange fruit salad to show (not the single apple and orange). Same with the Apple-orange-pear fruit salad -- if this is selected, I only want that specific salad to show, not the individual fruits.

But my code selects all the fruit - so for example, if you checkoff apple, orange and pear, it shows all associated fruit, when I only want the apple-orange-pear salad to show (the one unique selection). Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/daysable/41uusunm/

my code:

```
<style>
.box {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.apple {
    background: #F00;
}
.orange {
    background: #F60;
}
.pear {
    background: #FF0;
}
.fs-apple-orange {
    background: #F66;
}
.fs-orange-pear {
    background: #0C9;
}
.fs-apple-pear {
    background: #066;
}
.apple-orange-pear {
    background: #00F;
}
</style>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="apple" name="colorCheckbox" value="apple">apple</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="orange" name="colorCheckbox" value="orange">orange</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pear" name="colorCheckbox" value="pear">pear</label>
</div>
<div class="apple box">Apple</div>
<div class="orange box">Orange</div>
<div class="pear box">Pear</div>
<div class="fs-apple-orange box">Apple Orange Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="fs-orange-pear box">Orange Pear Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="fs-apple-pear box">Apple Pear Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="apple-orange-pear box">Apple Orange Pear Fruit Salad</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    if ($('#apple').is(':checked')) $('.apple.box').show();
    if ($('#orange').is(':checked')) $('.orange.box').show();
    if ($('#pear').is(':checked')) $('.pear.box').show();
    if ($('#apple').is(':checked') && !$('#orange').is(':checked')) {
        $('.fs-apple-orange.box').show();
    }
    if ($('#orange').is(':checked') && !$('#pear').is(':checked')) {
        $('.fs-orange-pear.box').show();
    }
    if ($('#apple').is(':checked') && $('#pear').is(':checked')) {
         $('.fs-apple-pear.box').show();
    }
    if ($('#apple').is(':checked') && $('#orange').is(':checked') && $('#pear').is(':checked'))  {
         $('.apple-orange-pear.box').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Won't solve your problem, but you should close your `input` tags like this: `<input ... />`

Comment: Also, when you post code, please try to avoid including space consuming things that are not relevant for the problem, like the CSS for the colors. It takes away focus. (Or maybe that is just me, I should stop nagging now.)

Comment: Sorry about that! I'll make a note for the future. New to posting here, so thank you for the tips!

Comment: @Anders that is xhtml requirement ... if use `<!DOCTYPE html>` you don't close them although both ways work. `<input>` is a `void element`

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements have some issues. A few of your conditions made no sense like

```
if ($('#apple').is(':checked') && !$('#orange').is(':checked'))
    $('.fs-apple-orange.box').show();
```

which would show the apple orange box when apple was checked and orange wasn't. For the single fruits you need to check that the others are false.

```js
$('.apple-orange-pear.box').show();
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    var apple=$('#apple').is(':checked');
    var orange=$('#orange').is(':checked');
    var pear=$('#pear').is(':checked');
    
 if (apple&&!orange && !pear) $('.apple.box').show();
    else if (!apple&&orange&&!pear) $('.orange.box').show();
 else if (!apple&&!orange&&pear) $('.pear.box').show();
    else if (apple && orange &&!pear) {
  $('.fs-apple-orange.box').show();
    }
 else if (!apple && orange && pear) {
  $('.fs-orange-pear.box').show();
    }
    else if (apple&&!orange&&pear) {
   $('.fs-apple-pear.box').show();
    }
    if (apple&&orange&&pear)  {
   $('.apple-orange-pear.box').show();
 }
});
```

```css
.box {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.apple {
    background: #F00;
}
.orange {
    background: #F60;
}
.pear {
    background: #FF0;
}
.fs-apple-orange {
 background: #F66;
}
.fs-orange-pear {
 background: #0C9;
}
.fs-apple-pear {
 background: #066;
}
.apple-orange-pear {
 background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="apple" name="colorCheckbox" value="apple" checked>apple</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="orange" name="colorCheckbox" value="orange"checked>orange</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pear" name="colorCheckbox" value="pear" checked>pear</label>
</div>
<div class="apple box">Apple</div>
<div class="orange box">Orange</div>
<div class="pear box">Pear</div>
<div class="fs-apple-orange box">Apple Orange Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="fs-orange-pear box">Orange Pear Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="fs-apple-pear box">Apple Pear Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="apple-orange-pear box">Apple Orange Pear Fruit Salad</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. this makes much more sense. It's exactly what I wanted the experience to be.

Comment: I want to show all three checkboxes checked by default. And the customer can uncheck as they see fit. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: thanks so much, this is great. But is there a way to show the checks checked as default too?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="colorCheckbox"]').click(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        var a = $('#apple').is(':checked');
        var o = $('#orange').is(':checked');
        var p = $('#pear').is(':checked');

        if(a && o && p)
            return $('.apple-orange-pear.box').show();
        if(a && p)
            return $('.fs-apple-pear.box').show();
        if(o && p)
            return $('.fs-orange-pear.box').show();
        if(a && o)
            return $('.fs-apple-orange.box').show();
        if(a)
            return $('.apple.box').show();
        if(o)
            return $('.orange.box').show();
        if(p)
            return $('.pear.box').show();   
});
```

```js
$('input[name="colorCheckbox"]').click(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        var a = $('#apple').is(':checked');
        var o = $('#orange').is(':checked');
        var p = $('#pear').is(':checked');
        
        if(a && o && p)
      return $('.apple-orange-pear.box').show();
        if(a && p)
      return $('.fs-apple-pear.box').show();
        if(o && p)
      return $('.fs-orange-pear.box').show();
        if(a && o)
      return $('.fs-apple-orange.box').show();
     if(a)
            return $('.apple.box').show();
        if(o)
            return $('.orange.box').show();
     if(p)
            return $('.pear.box').show();   
});
```

```css
.box {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.apple {
    background: #F00;
}
.orange {
    background: #F60;
}
.pear {
    background: #FF0;
}
.fs-apple-orange {
 background: #F66;
}
.fs-orange-pear {
 background: #0C9;
}
.fs-apple-pear {
 background: #066;
}
.apple-orange-pear {
 background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="apple" name="colorCheckbox" value="apple">apple</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="orange" name="colorCheckbox" value="orange">orange</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pear" name="colorCheckbox" value="pear">pear</label>
</div>
<div class="apple box">Apple</div>
<div class="orange box">Orange</div>
<div class="pear box">Pear</div>
<div class="fs-apple-orange box">Apple Orange Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="fs-orange-pear box">Orange Pear Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="fs-apple-pear box">Apple Pear Fruit Salad</div>
<div class="apple-orange-pear box">Apple Orange Pear Fruit Salad</div>
```

Comment: @KristinMann does that answers your question completely? ot you need any information

Comment: I want to show all three checkboxes checked by default. And the customer can uncheck as they see fit. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This will work no matter what fruits you have and how many of them.

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("input[name=colorCheckbox]").click(function() {

        //Get a list of the checked fruits.
        fruits = jQuery("input[name=colorCheckbox]:checked").map(function() {
            return this.id;            
        }).get().sort().join("-");

        //Hide all boxes.
        jQuery(".box").hide();

        //Show the relevant one.
        jQuery(".fs-" + fruits).show();

    });

});
```

Just make sure to have all the class names set up as `fs-fruit1-fruit2`, with the fruit names are sorted in alphabetical order (like `fs-apple-pear`).

On a side note, you should put all your script in the `<head>`, and instead wrap it like this `jQuery(function() { /* CODE */ });`. jQuery will not run the code until the DOM is ready.

Also, if you only have one `div` per `fs-...` tag you might want to use it as an ID instead of a class, since matching by ID is faster than matching by class.

Here is the jQuery documentation on [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: as long as order is maintained between class name structure and order of checkboxes. Not always intuitive for some. Switching checkbox positions would make the whole thing fall apart

Comment: I was already working on the edit, but thanks for pointing that out. Both sharp and quick.

Comment: I considered a similar approach but seemed fragile, opted for array matching instead

Comment: Hm, didn't think about the problem of changing the order. Added a `sort()` to solve that. Perhpas not necesarry to sort, but I don't think there will be a thousand fruits so it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

A more scalable approach is to set the filter values in data attributes as json array on the box elements .

```
<div class="box"  data-filters='["pear"]'>Pear</div>
<div class="box"  data-filters='["apple","orange"]'>Apple Orange Fruit Salad</div>
```

These can be read as arrays using jQuery `data()`.

Then you can use generic array matching code that doesn't care what the specific values you use are, or how many checkboxes there are .... just that they match between checkbox value and array value

```
var $checks=$('input[type="checkbox"]');

$checks.click(function () {
    // create array of checkbox values
    var values=$checks.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return this.value
    }).get();
    // hide all the boxes and start filtering for matches
    $('.box').hide().filter(function(){
        // read filter array from box element
        var filterArr = $(this).data('filters');
       // reject if array lengths differ
       if(filterArr.length !== values.length){
          return false;
       }
        // check for all values matching between checkboxes and box filters
        var isMatch = filterArr.filter(function(val){
             return values.indexOf(val) >-1
        }).length === values.length;

        return isMatch
     // show the matching elemnts  
    }).show();
});
```

Now when you get a new item in the mix, you don't have to refactor the code, just follow the same html format

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ektgLddf/)**</kbd>